# Edit records using FroalaEdior in Angular 5

Tags: angular5, froala

In my angular 5 application, i am using FroalaEditor to get text users enter and save the records to database. This i was able to archive, but now i am find it difficult to make it possible for users to edit their save records using the FroalaEditor.

In my `.component.ts` file i have been able to get the record the user want to edit and story it to a variable. Like so,

```
this.conService.getCaseHistory().subscribe(
          data => {
              this.db_case_history = data['case_history'];
          }
      );
```

And in my `.html` file i am doing this,

```
 <div  name="case_history" [froalaEditor]>
     {{db_case_history}}
 </div>
```

But the content of the variable is not appearing in the editor. I am grateful to anyone that will put through achieving this use this same editor or anyone other one in angular 5.

Answer (score 0):

Guys this might help you if you come across this issue, i was able to achieve it by doing a two way data binding on the div tag, like so